# converting string to date in php in "ymd"

Tags: php, datetime

hello please help me to convert string into date:-
have googled about this but didnt get desired result

```
    <?php

$todaydate= $_GET['date']; //sending 201213 ie index.php?date=201213

$todaydate=preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $todaydate);

echo $todaydate."----------"; //prints 201213

$todaydate = date("ymd", strtotime($todaydate));

echo $todaydate."----------"; // i want to print 131220 here but it prints today's date
?>
```

Comment: You seem to be assuming that `strtotime()` is somehow magical/omniscient/psychic and can handle ANY date you throw at it. It isn't and can't... You need to feed it a date string it **CAN** handle, or use string operations + mktime() to tear apart your date string. And exactly **WHAT** is `201213`? 13th month of 2012? 13th day? if **WE** can't tell what it is, what makes you think PHP could figure it out?

Comment: you need correct formated date input.SEE formats: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: or any way to convert 201213 to 131220 !!

Comment: Is that 20(d)12(m)13(y) ?

Comment: yes. it is 20(d)12(m)13(y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with [mktime](https://www.php.net/mktime):

```
<?php
    $todaydate  = $_GET['date']; //sending 201213 ie index.php?date=201213
    $todaydate  = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $todaydate);
    echo $todaydate."----------"; //prints 201213
    
    $d = substr($todaydate, 0, 2);
    $m = substr($todaydate, 2, 2);
    $y = substr($todaydate, 4, 2);
    $t = mktime (0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
    
    $todaydate = date("ymd", $t);
    echo $todaydate."----------"; // i want to print 131220 here but it prints today's date
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

more simple solutoin:

```
<?php
        $todaydate  = $_GET['date']; //sending 201213 ie index.php?date=201213
        $todaydate  = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $todaydate);   
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', $todaydate);
        echo $date->format('ymd');
?>
```

with this code you can use any format to display your date as you have a valid date now.